# RAID Level Recommendation

Tags: linux, raid

I have just purchased the Dedicated server with the following specification.

```
XEON 3.46GHZ 2 CPU
64GB RAM
6x300 GB Harddrive
```

I wanted to know what RAID level should be installed with these hard-drives and specification. I ill install WHM/Cpanel on the server with mysql.

Comment: RAID level can be determined based on your capacity and performance requirements. We can not help you without providing more details about your setup, usage, and requirements.

Answer (score 2):

[raid10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels). Did You plan to go with hardware drive or software? If hw raid, did You have battery backed cache?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we have hardware raid and yes we have battery backed cache.

Comment: then hardware raid10 and you got about 900GB usable disk space.